# How do I install OpenLayers in a Rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline, openlayers

I am close but seem to be missing something.  I have dropped `OpenLayers.js` in `app/assets/javascripts`, the `theme` folder in `app/assets/stylesheets` and the `img` folder in `app/assets`.

I have `*= require theme/default/style.css` in my `application.css` file and `//= require OpenLayers` in my `application.js` file.

I am trying to load an OpenLayers map in my `locations.js.coffee` file but the img folder fails.  OpenLayers tries to load the image files from `/locations/img/...` vs. `/img/...` which doesn't seem to work either.

I am still fuzzy on the asset pipeline in Rails and I am sure I am doing this wrong.  I can't seem to find a concrete example of the best way to install OpenLayers in a Rails app.  Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: you need to  enable assests pipeline if your app is less than rails 3.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Drop the complete openlayers directory in `vendor/assets/javascripts` (to save some space I made a symbolic link):

```
vendor/assests/javascripts/openlayers
```

Add `//= openlayers/OpenLayers` to the `app/assets/javascripts/application.js`:

```
//= require openlayers/OpenLayers
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
```

Comment: This takes care of loading the js, but doesn't address the css stylesheets and related image assets.

Comment: You don't have to address css and images assets because openlayers will do that for you. By keeping the openlayer dir as is it knows where to find its css and image assets

Comment: I believe this depends on the results of OL internal calls to OpenLayers._getScriptLocation(), where it is looking for assets with certain names in mind, and will break once you get to production environments with precompiled assets, since the asset names will have an MD5 hash appended to them, and OL won't know to look for that.

Comment: KenB, you may very well be right didn't think of that, was just playing with it in development.

Comment: You can try to do what this guy did in this gem: https://github.com/tmikoss/openlayers-rails

He just sets OpenLayers._getScriptLocation() and it seems to work for me in production, dunno about the asset names and MD5 hashes. To clarify I'm not using the gem but I just copied his layout to vendor. I did this because at some point I will want to customize my build of OpenLayers because I'm actually using it for something unrelated to mapping and probably can strip out much of the code.

Comment: Oh, if you try that, you need to make sure to force it to precompile the theme CSS too as in https://github.com/tmikoss/openlayers-rails/blob/master/lib/openlayers-rails.rb .

Comment: @Ibrahim could you elaborate on how you copied the folder structure and what other files you needed to create? I'm having problems getting the gem to work in production (it can't find the style.css file)

Answer (score 1):

First of all put your images in `assets/images` folder. That will make them accessible via `http://localhost/assets/yourimage.png`

Default behaviour in OpenLayers is to fetch images from `img` folder that should be located on the same level as OpenLayers.js in tree structure, which is not the case in Rails application.

To override this behaviour and make OpenLayers read images from Rails images catalog you should set the global variable `OpenLayers.ImgPath = "/assets"`

Comment: That would work.  Can I not keep everything in the `img` directory so that down the road it's easier to find / upgrade those files if they are segregated?  Also what about the vendor/assets path?  Could I not install these here?

Comment: You can keep images in img directory but then you'll have to move it to images folder. Path to images will then be /assets/img/iamge.png Rails assumes that your assets are either in images, stylesheets or javascripts folder. The same applies for vendor folder.